# how to get default timezone time in moment timezone

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment timezone to set default time

**$moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/London');
$moment().toString();**

is providing me the time in the defined timezone. but I need the timestamp. so I am using

**$moment().now();**

but it's returning the timestamp in local timezone. how can I get the timestamp of the default timezone(Europe/London)?

Answer (score 1):

Moment.now is not really a public api. It is intended to be used for testing purposes only. All that you want to do is format a moment, so your code would be as follows:

```
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/London'); 
moment().format(); //"2016-10-18T21:57:39+01:00"
```

Comment: how can I get it in milliseconds?